# cin and getline skipping input

Tags: c++, input, getline, cin

earlier i posted a question about `cin` skipping input, and I got results to flush, and use `istringstream`, but now I tried every possible solution but none of them work.

here is my code:

```
void createNewCustomer () {
    string name, address;

    cout << "Creating a new customer..." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the customer's name: "; getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter the customer's address: "; getline(cin, address);

    Customer c(name, address, 0);
    CustomerDB::addCustomer(c);

    cout << endl;
}
```

but I'm still getting the same thing, skipping input, and when it does take input, it takes them and stores in name empty nothing, and in address it takes what i wrote in name but from the 2nd letter to the end

what is wrong with my code?

I tried the `cin.ignore()`, `cin.get()`, and `cin.clear()` all of them together and alone, none of them worked

EDIT:

main method in main.cpp invokes `mainMenu()` only

```
void mainMenu () {
    char choice;

    do {
        system("cls");
        mainMenuDisplay();
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");

        switch (choice) {
            case '1':
                customerMenu();
                break;

            case '2':
                dvdMenu();
                break;

            case '3':
                receiptMenu();
                break;

            case '4':
                outro();
                break;

            default:
                cout << '\a';
        }

        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    } while (choice != '4');
}
```

i will choose 1 for the customer example, this is `customerMenu()`

```
void customerMenu () {
    char choice;

    do {
        system("cls");
        manageCustomerMenu();
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");

        switch (choice) {
            case '1':
                createNewCustomer();
                break;

            case '2':
                deleteCustomer();
                break;

            case '3':
                updateCustomerStatus();
                break;

            case '4':
                viewCustomersList();
                break;

            case '5':
                mainMenu();
                break;

            default:
                cout << '\a';
        }

        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    } while (choice != '5');
}
```

I choose 1 again to create a new customer object, which will now go to the MainFunctions.cpp which will invoke the function `createNewCustomer()` which is the first one.

```
void createNewCustomer () {
    string name, address;

    cout << "Creating a new customer..." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the customer's name: "; cin.getline(name,256);
    cout << "Enter the customer's address: "; cin.getline(address,256);

    Customer c(name, address, 0);
    CustomerDB::addCustomer(c);

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete compileable example.  If that's difficult, please at least show the function from which this function is called.

Comment: ok, i will edit the question to include what somehow resembles a stack trace and a screen shot of the example

Comment: you said you tried cin.ignore.  give the code, it should have worked.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you're using `getline` after `cin >> something`, you need to flush the newline out of the buffer in between.

My personal favourite for this if no characters past the newline are needed is `cin.sync()`. However, it is implementation defined, so it might not work the same way as it does for me. For something solid, use `cin.ignore()`. Or make use of `std::ws` to remove leading whitespace if desirable:

```
int a;

cin >> a;
cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
//discard characters until newline is found

//my method: cin.sync(); //discard unread characters

string s;
getline (cin, s); //newline is gone, so this executes

//other method: getline(cin >> ws, s); //remove all leading whitespace
```

Comment: `sync()` is not defined to do that, though it may work in some instances.  It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, it's always worked perfectly for me. Can you find some documentation where it's not supposed to clear out the unread characters?

Comment: i didnt use cin before the getline in the function `createNewCustomer()`, but it is used in the functions calling `createNewCustomer()` like in `mainMenu()` and `customerMenu()`

Comment: @aizen92, any time you `cin >> something`, it will leave a newline in the buffer. The buffer remains when you switch functions, as long as you're still using `cin`. If the next operation to do with `cin` is `getline`, it will read that leftover newline and seem to skip getting input.

Comment: I'll get that doc reference for you in a minute.  In the meantime, here's something for you to ponder: http://ideone.com/7ICvn

Comment: i added the `cin.sync()` after every `cin >> <something>` i used, and it worked
thanks

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I see your point, but seeing as how I use GCC, could that example have something to do with the fact that you enter all input beforehand? That does kind of change the logic of such things.

Comment: Here ya go.  n3242, the last C++11 draft, §27.9.1.5/19 -- *"int sync() Effects: If a put area exists, calls filebuf::overflow to write the characters to the file. If a get area
exists, the effect is implementation-defined."*

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, ah there it is. I'll reflect that in my answer.

Comment: @chris: What OS are you using?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Windows, works the same on XP as 7.

Comment: @chris: That explains the difference.  I don't think it matters that you're on GCC.  I'm guessing, but I'm not sure, that it has something to do with the way Linux treats everything as a file.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, that would make sense. I don't really use Linux too often, so I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: What if the user types more than 80 characters in a line? Prefer: `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: @Robᵩ, I sort of left the character limit implied in the comment. I haven't read way in-depth into the input buffer either. I do prefer it for the console as it is shorter than `ignore()` and achieves the same effect there. I agree that it isn't a good choice for files, and apparently not for consoles either if the code is being used in more than one place.

Comment: @Rob: *"if input is from a terminal, .sync() destroys the remainder of the line."* -- This is not the case for me.  The results on my machine are exactly as what happens in the example I gave from ideone.  That is to say, cin.sync() appears to do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - Your experience and further research on my part reveal my prior statement to be hogwash. I'm deleting that comment. FYI: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46624#c1

Comment: @Robᵩ I have always disliked `ignore()` for this reason. Thank you for mentioning `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` I did not known about it and now using `ignore()` is back on the table for me.

Comment: Thanks, had been struggling with this for quite sometime.

Comment: cin.ignore() worked for me!

Answer (score 18):

The structure of your menu code is the issue:

```
cin >> choice;   // new line character is left in the stream

 switch ( ... ) {
     // We enter the handlers, '\n' still in the stream
 }

cin.ignore();   // Put this right after cin >> choice, before you go on
                // getting input with getline.
```

Comment: This worked for me quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Here, the `'\n'` left by cin, is creating issues.

```
do {
    system("cls");
    manageCustomerMenu();
    cin >> choice;               #This cin is leaving a trailing \n
    system("cls");

    switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            createNewCustomer();
            break;
```

This `\n` is being consumed by next getline in `createNewCustomer()`. You should use getline instead -

```
do {
    system("cls");
    manageCustomerMenu();
    getline(cin, choice)               
    system("cls");

    switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            createNewCustomer();
            break;
```

I think this would resolve the issue.

Comment: To use `getline` you'd need to change `choice` to string, then it couldn't be used like that in the `switch`: you could use `choice[0]` but that would hide errors (e.g. '11' would get treated as 1, but that's also the case for the accepted error that ignores the rest of the line.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue, and resolved this issue using getchar() to catch the ('\n') new char