# Problems with getline() function?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the `getline` function in the code below. In the "get" info section I want to be able to store a whole sentence, but I can't make it work.

When I open up my program it just skips the input for the info.

p.s: I'm new to C++

Here is the section of the code where i have the problem (Enter the information):

```
void add() {
    string name;
    string faction;
    string classe;
    string race;
    string info;

    ofstream wowdatabase("wowdatabase.txt", ios::app);
    cout << "Add a race or class" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the name of the race or class (only small letters!):" << endl;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter Race (Type -, if writen in name section):" << endl;
    cin >> race;

    cout << "Enter Class (Type -, if writen in name section):" << endl;
    cin >> classe;

    cout << "Enter faction (Alliance/Horde):" << endl;
    cin >> faction;

    cout << "Enter the information:" << endl;
    getline(cin, info);

    wowdatabase << name << ' ' << faction << ' ' << classe << ' ' << race << ' ' << info << endl;
    wowdatabase.close();
    system("CLS");
    main();
}
```

Now it works fine =) but, when i want to output the info again it only shows the first word in the sentence?

Comment: Just a little thing here : `cout << "" << endl;`you don't need the `""`, just `cout << endl;` will suffice.

Comment: Calling `main`'s illegal in C++.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input

Answer (score 2):

Before this statement

```
getline(cin, info);
```

make the following call

```
cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

To use this call you must include header `<limits>`.

The problem is that after executing statement

```
cin >> faction;
```

the new line character that corresponds to enetered key ENTER is in the input buffer and the next getline call reads this character.

Answer (score 0):

After you read fraction an empty line character will be left over. The consequent call to `getline` will read it. To avoid that add a call to [cin.ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) before the `getline` call.