# Looping runtime-error

Tags: c++, class, loops, multiple-inheritance, do-while

I have made a really simple game using c++. Most of it works just fine but whenever I try to replay the game, the value doesn't reset and continues where I last left off and that's is not what I want it to happens. Like lets say, in my first try, I defeated the enemy and it health is zero and when I retry it, the value doesn't starts off by 100 but it starts off from zero. And I really want a fix to that. Anyway, here is my code("It's pretty long):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Health{
private:
    int health;
    Health(const Health& cpy){
        health = cpy.health;
    }
public:
     Health(){
        health = 100;
    }
    void display_health(){
        cout << "Health: " << health << endl;
    }

    Health& operator -=(int atk){
        health -= atk;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator <(int compare){
        return (health < compare);
    }
    bool operator >(int compare){
        return !(this->operator<(compare));
    }
    bool operator &&(const int compare){
        return (health && compare);
    }
};

class Hero : public Health{
public:
    void kick(){
        cout << "Your kick damaged 45 health points" << endl;
    }
    void Punch(){
        cout << "Your punch damaged 25 health points" << endl;
    }
    void Knife(){
        cout << "Your kinfe damaged 60 health points" << endl;
    }
    void Tackle(){
        cout << "Your tackle damaged 10 health points" << endl;
    }
};

class Enemy : public Health{
public:
    void Basic_hit(){
        cout << "Enemy damaged you by 25 point" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    //local vaiables 
    string name;
    int choice;
    string ply_agn = "y";
    //instance
    Hero hero;
    Enemy enmy;
    //user interface
    do{ //entire game repeats
        cout << "Enter you character name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Your default health is : ";
        hero.display_health();
        cout << endl;
        do{
            //user interface
            cout << "0.Kick - 45" << endl;
            cout << "1.Punch - 25 " << endl;
            cout << "2.Kinfe -  60" << endl;
            cout << "3.Tackle - 10 " << endl;
            //players choice
            cout << "Which move you like to chose: ";
            cin >> choice;
            cout << endl;
            //switch function
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 0:
                hero.kick();
                cout << "Enemy ";
                enmy -= 45;
                enmy.display_health();
                break;
            case 1:
                hero.Punch();
                cout << "Enemy ";
                enmy -= 25;
                enmy.display_health();
                break;
            case 2:
                hero.Knife();
                cout << "Enemy ";
                enmy -= 60;
                enmy.display_health();
                break;
            case 3:
                hero.Tackle();
                cout << "Enemy ";
                enmy -= 10;
                enmy.display_health();
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid move! Try again" << endl;
                break;
            }
            cout << endl;
            //Enemy move 
            enmy.Basic_hit();
            hero -= 25;
            cout << "The enemy hit you with a basic hit. You recieved 25 damage" << endl;
            cout << "Your ";
            hero.display_health();
            cout << endl;
        } while (enmy > 0);
        //winning condition
        if (enmy < 0 && hero > 0) {
            cout << "You won" << endl;
        }
        else if (hero < 0 && enmy > 0){
            cout << "You lose" << endl;
        }
        else if (hero < 0 && enmy < 0){
            cout << "This game is a draw" << endl;
        }
    } while (ply_agn == "y"); //This is where I think is messing up the game

        //repeating condition
        cout << "Would you like to play again: ";
        cin >> ply_agn;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And thank you for your time

Answer (score 4):

Put the

```
Hero hero;
Enemy enmy;
```

after the `do{`, like

```
...
string ply_agn = "y";
//user interface
do{ //entire game repeats
    //instance
    Hero hero;
    Enemy enmy;
    ...
```

Comment: Ha ha ninja'd you by 3 seconds, but you took the time to actually write code so upvote for you.

Answer (score 4):

As others have stated, you need to put your `Hero` and `Enemy` objects inside your loop, so they get recreated after every loop of the game.

Another bug in your program is that you [mix `getline` with `cin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553849/1670308), so in your next loop you won't be able to give your character a new name. To avoid this, you'll need to place a `cin.ignore` before your `getline()` function call, like this

```
cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
getline(cin, name);
```

Here, [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is defined in the header `<limits>` and is used because it is the maximum size of the stream, so it will ignore as many newline characters `\n` were  left in the buffer by `cin`.

As a final thought, you need to the repeat question **before** the loop test, like this

```
    cout << "Would you like to play again: ";
    cin >> ply_agn;
} while (ply_agn == "y");
```

otherwise `ply_agn` will be always `y`, and the user won't be able to quit your game ever :-)

Answer (score 2):

You never explicitly reset the health at the start of the game. If you're going to reset via looping like this, the first step in the game should be to reset both `Hero` and `Enemy`. Simply moving where you declare them to be the first line in your `do while` loop should do the trick.