# read strings from input till EOF

Tags: c++, io, eof, getline

I have gone through many posts on SO , but still i am not able to resolve the issue .
I have to read :

> text
>   pattern1
>   pattern2

from standard input , there are many `text and patterns` .
**Code** :

```
string t,p1,p2;
while(getline(cin, t))
{
    cin>>p1;
    cin>>p2;

    cout<<"text is = "<<t<<"\np1 is = "<<p1<<"\np2 is = "<<p2<<endl;
}
```

**Input file** :

> hammer
>   ham
>   mer
>   gogoa
>   go
>   z
>   gogoa
>   g
>   o

**Output** :

> text is = hammer
>   p1 is = ham
>   p2 is = mer
>   text is =
>   p1 is = gogoa
>   p2 is = go
>   text is =
>   p1 is = z
>   p2 is = gogoa
>   text is =
>   p1 is = g
>   p2 is = o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using getline after `cin >> something`, you need to flush the newline out of the buffer in between.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string t,p1,p2;
    while(getline(cin, t))
    {
        cin>>p1;
        cin>>p2;

        cout<<"text is = "<<t<<"\np1 is = "<<p1<<"\np2 is = "<<p2<<endl;

        cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Dump everything until newline
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/b7Xj6o

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553849/1938163

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like this:

```
#include <vector>

vector<string> vs;
int i;
while(getline(cin, t)) {
    vs.push_back(t);
}

for(i = 0; i < (vs.size / 3); i++) {
    cout <<"text is " << vs[0 + (3*i)] << "\np1 is " << vs[1 + (3*i)] << "\np2 is " << vs[2 + (3*i) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string t,p1,p2;
while(getline(cin, t))
{
    cin>>p1;
    cin>>p2;

    getchar();  //removes '\n' from stdin

    cout<<"text is = "<<t<<"\np1 is = "<<p1<<"\np2 is = "<<p2<<endl;
}
```