# C++ Why does this work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, switch-statement

I am using Microsoft Visual studio 2013

I currently have this switch statement:

```
switch (option)
{
        case 1:
            getline(cin, newname);
            cout << "What would you like your new username to be?\nName: ";
            getline(cin, newname);
            name = newname;
            cout << "\nYour username is now '" << name << "' with your balance being $" << balance << "\n";
            options();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "\nOpenning cheat menu\n";
            cheats();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\nExitting to main title...\n";
            title();
            break;
}
```

you can just ignore the case 2 and default, just showing so you know that those cases work. Case 2 and default work perfectly fine but case 1 is acting weird. As you can see on case 1 I have two getline(cin, newname); You may think I should only have one, but for some reason I need two for this code to function correctly.

If I only have one of these the code jumps past the input the user should give. If I have two it works normally.

I have asked someone this and they do not understand either, so therefore: Why does this work.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Add `cin.ignore();` before your `getline()`. That should fix you up. `getline()` leaves the new line character in the input stream.

Comment: @Icemanind: No, `getline` does not "leave the new line character in the input stream." The advice to use `ignore` is good though.

Comment: @Icemanind it reads it but doesn't add it to the string, instead discards it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you have leftover input including a newline, in the **input buffer** of `cin`. That happens when you use other input operations than `getline`. They generally don't consume everything in the input buffer.

Instead of the extra `getline` you *can* use `ignore`, but better, do that at the place where you earlier do the inputting.

Answer (score 0):

I think a similar problem has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input).

You need to flush the newline with cin.ignore() or cin.sync().

The first call also seems misplaced...