# Using cin function

Tags: c++, cin

The following code doesn't give the second prompt to "enter message". How do I fix it?

```
cout << "Enter shifts:" << endl;
cin >> shifts;
cout << "Enter message:" << endl;
getline(cin, msg);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cin and getline skipping input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
cout << "Enter shifts:" << endl;
cin >> shifts;
cout << "Enter message:" << endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, msg);
```

use `cin.ignore();` before using `getline` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. But do I always have to manually flush the buffer?

Comment: Is `cin.ignore()` similar to `cin >> ws`? I think I'd probably use the latter in this case.

Comment: @ANKI_YUME, maybe you could also opt for creating a function that wraps both calls and have it return your input by value, which may get elided by NRVO if its a larger type, or take a reference and input it directly to that,  similar to what `std::getline` does.

Answer (score 1):

when you enter shifts there is  a newline which read by geline funtion. So You need to ignore that newline.

write :

```
cout << "Enter shifts:" << endl;
cin >> shifts;
getchar();
cout << "Enter message:" << endl;
getline(cin, msg);
```