# cin is skipping a line

Tags: c++, cin, getline

Here's a segment of code that I am working on:

```
std::cout << "Enter title of book: ";
std::string title;
std::getline(std::cin, title);
std::cout << "Enter author's name: ";
std::string author;
std::getline(std::cin, author);
std::cout << "Enter publishing year: ";
int pub;
std::cin >> pub;
std::cout << "Enter number of copies: ";
int copies;
std::cin >> copies;
```

Here's the output from this section when it is running (added quotes):

```
"Enter title of book: Enter author's name":
```

How do I fix this so that I can enter in the title?

Comment: The (currently) two answers provide solutions for what is very likely the problem, but the question is missing [the completeness requirement of MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and cannot be answered with with certainty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cin and getline skipping input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some input before that you don't show us. Assuming you do you can use `std::cin.ignore()` to ignore any newlines left from `std::cin`.

```
  std::string myInput;
  std::cin >> myInput; // this is some input you never included.
  std::cin.ignore(); // this will ignore \n that std::cin >> myInput left if you pressed enter.

  std::cout << "Enter title of book: ";
  std::string title;
  std::getline(std::cin, title);
  std::cout << "Enter author's name: ";
```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`getline` is newline delimited. However, reading with something like `std::cin` leaves the newline in the input stream. As [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) recommends, when switching from whitespace delimited to newline delimited input, you want to clean all newlines from the input stream by doing a `cin.ignore`: for example, `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`. (Of course, I am assuming you left out the `cin` before `getline` when distilling your code into an MCVE).