# String with character spacing

Tags: c++

This program works EXCEPT that it does not allow a space between the first and last name. Below is an example as to what I am talking about:

[Link to Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW4sT.png)

Can someone please help me to fix this? I believe it is in **string playerName** as it will not accept a space between the first and last name.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Structure to hold the Player Data
struct Player {
    string playerName;
    int playerNumber;
    int pointsScored;

};

// Function Prototypes
void getPlayerInfo(Player &);
void showInfo(Player[], int);
int getTotalPoints(Player[], int);
void showHighest(Player[], int);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int N = 12;
    Player players[N];
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        cout << "\nPLAYER #" << i + 1 << "\n";
        cout << "---------\n";
        getPlayerInfo(players[i]);
}

    showInfo(players, N);
    int totalPoints = getTotalPoints(players, N);
    cout << "TOTAL POINTS: " << totalPoints << "\n";
    cout << "The player who scored the most points is :";
    showHighest(players, N);
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}


void getPlayerInfo(Player &P) {
    cout << "Player Name:";
    //cin >> P.playerName;                            **CHANGED THIS**
      cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');
    std::getline(std::cin, P.playerName);                **TO THIS**
    do {
        cout << "Player Number:";
        cin >> P.playerNumber;
        if (P.playerNumber<0)
            cout << "invalid Input\n";
    } while (P.playerNumber<0);
    do {
        cout << "Points Scored:";
        cin >> P.pointsScored;
        if (P.pointsScored<0)
            cout << "invalid Input\n";
    } while (P.pointsScored<0);

}


void showInfo(Player P[], int N) {
    cout << "\nNAME" << "\t\tNUMBER" << "\t\tPOINTS SCORED" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        cout << P[i].playerName << "\t\t" << P[i].playerNumber << "\t\t" << P[i].pointsScored << "\n";
}

int getTotalPoints(Player P[], int N) {
    int Points = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        Points += (P[i].pointsScored);
    return Points;
}


void showHighest(Player P[], int N) {
    int HighestPoint = P[0].pointsScored;
    string Name = P[0].playerName;
    for (int i = 1; i<N; i++) {
        if (HighestPoint<P[i].pointsScored) {
            HighestPoint = P[i].pointsScored;
            Name = P[i].playerName;
        }
    }
    cout << Name;
}
```

Comment: You should shorten this to the [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) parts, but I bet it's because `cin >> some_string;` treats `' '` as the delimiter, not `'\n'`.

Comment: it is in function: void getPlayerInfo; where it says cin >> P.playerName

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't link to external images. But secondly, I don't see what's wrong with the image. It looks fine to me.

Comment: take out the `ignore` before the `std::getline`

Comment: @M.M he needs the ignore because if he does `getline` after `cin>>` sometime is skips the `getline`.

Comment: @789 any such `ignore` should appear immediately after the `cin>>`

Answer (score 3):

When `std::cin` uses `operator>>` to insert into a `std::string`, it stops reading at space (`' '`) characters. Use `std::getline` instead.

```
std::getline(std::cin, P.playerName); //read everything up to '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code:

```
void getPlayerInfo(Player &P) {
cout << "Player Name:";
cin >> P.playerName;//<<----
```

cin treats ' ' (space) as a delimiter. If you want to have an input with ' ' (space) you need to use: (thanks to @James Root)

```
//before doing get line make sure input buffer is empty
```

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553849/3013996

```
cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
std::getline(std::cin,P.playerName);
```

Comment: `cin::getline` is for arrays. `std::getline` is what you wanted to be using.

Comment: I edited the original but and it does work, EXCEPT now after you enter the first Player's Name, Player's Number, Player's Score. Then it goes to the second Player it skips the Player Name and goes directly to the Player Number. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok so I got it to work for the first part                                                EXCEPT now in function: void showInfo                                                       it shows only the last name. I am sure it is the part:                               cout << P[i].playerName