# Program writing record twice in a binary file in c++

Tags: c++, stream, inputstream, fileinputstream, turbo-c++

kindly check the code for error as it is writing the record twice in the file. I think error maybe due to `eof()` function. I have provided class description too just in case.

```
class student
{
    int sno;
    char sname[20];
    float fees;
public:
    void input()
    {
        cout << "enter sno,sname and fees \n";
        cin >> sno;
        gets(sname);
        cin >> fees;
    }
    void output()
    {
        cout << sno << "\t" << sname << "\t" << fees << "\n";
    }
    int rsno()
    {
        return sno;
    }
}s;

void add()
{
    ofstream f1;
    f1.open("stu.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);
    s.input();
    f1.write((char*)&s, sizeof(s));
    f1.close();
}
void displayall()
{
    ifstream f2;
    f2.open("stu.dat", ios::binary);
    while (!f2.eof())
    {
        f2.read((char*)&s, sizeof(s));
        s.output();
    }
    f2.close();
}
void main()
{
    add();
    displayall()
}
```

Comment: It does not appear that the code posted will do what you said is happening.  Can you post an [mcve]?

Comment: @NathanOliver i have edited the code showing how i intend to add records and then display them but somehow the last record gets written twice.

Comment: As is your code should not even compile.  Please provide a compile-able example.  You should also indent your code correctly.  I have done it this tmie to show you how it should look.

Comment: my code does compile in turboc++ without any error. the only problem i have is mentioned above.

Comment: also can you specify what have you changed because it appears exactly the same with just changes in my output messages.

Comment: It shouldn't as you do not have a `;` after `displayall()`.  Turbo C++ is an very old compiler and should not be used.  There are a number of free compilers out there that are much better and quite a bit more standard compliant.

Comment: It did change anything except the indentation.  If you check the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35015805/revisions) you can see how it looked vs how it looks now.

Comment: okkk i may have made that mistake while copying buy anyway could you explain the main problem

Comment: i agree turboc++ shouldnt be used but thats what we are taught on and asked to use :)

Answer (score 0):

Appears you have not declared an instance of `student`, so you must do so before calling its methods;

```
student s;
s.input();
```

By the way, that code dosen't seem to look like it works at first glance

Comment: It dosen't really look like you have declared it, if any compiler errors, please provide them in your question.

Comment: No compilation errors whatsoever with turboc++. I have declared s just before ending the class declaratio. it is allowed to do it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is too few code to give any statement. Is s a student instance? Are you trying to cast it to char array this way? I think you should use some serialization first.

BTW. It is ugliest formatting I've ever seend - pretty unreadable

Comment: I have given my full code now. i am basically adding records in the binary file which are of type 'student'.

Comment: BTW this is how we were taught to write the code in turboc++ :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an object/instance of the class `student` in the function before you can call it. You are incorrectly assuming that by creating the class and giving it an alias, you can now call it using `s.input`. You **have to** declare it in the function you're going to use it in. `student stu;` or `s stu;` at the start of the `void add()` function.

Also, since you're using C++, I'd highly advise you to use `getline` or even `fgets()` instead of `gets` since the latter is a C function and it is also depreciated and unsafe to use. If you do, I'd suggest taking a look at [Using Cin and Getline together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input). Handling the newline character is very important if you don't want to mess that up.

Comment: It all works fine I figured out the problem. It is based on the eof I used. I have answered it myself now you can read it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but I figured out the answer. The thing is there is some kind of buffer while using eof() function and that is why I was getting repeated results.