# getline (cin, string) is not excuted last line of code

Tags: c++

I have the following simple program, but the last line of code `getline(cin, topicClass)` is never excuted. However, if I use normal `cin>>topicClass` that is executed. Could you please help me out of this? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void InfoInput()
{
    string classID;
    string teacherName;
    int totalStudent;
    string topicClass;
    cout<<"Enter class ID"<<endl;
    getline(cin, classID);
    cout<<"Enter teacher's name"<<endl;
    getline(cin, teacherName);
    cout<<"Enter total number of students"<<endl;
    cin>>totalStudent;
    cout<<"Enter topic of class"<<endl;
    getline(cin, topicClass);
    //cin>>topicClass;
}

int main ()
{

    InfoInput();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input

Comment: Possible, nothing. That's a "Nailed it!" @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: How did you determine the `getline` was never executed?

Comment: Off topic: if `cin>>totalStudent;` is not provided an integer (even a horribly impossible integer than can't fit in an `int`) `cin` will be put in an error state that is not cleared, probably killing your program dead. You need to check the state of `cin`, or any other stream, after each read to make sure data was read and to clean up the mess if it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is above, with this line:

```
cin>>totalStudent;
```

This does not read a line. You enter your input and (I assume) you press ENTER. The `\n` remains in the buffer of `std::cin` and is read as an empty line with your next instruction:

```
getline(cin, topicClass);
```

To fix, use this code:

```
cin>>totalStudent;
while(std::isspace(cin.peek())
    cin.ignore();
cout<<"Enter topic of class"<<endl;
getline(cin, topicClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `\n` remained in `cin` after reading `totalStudent` as integer so you need to get that `\n` first out of the system and then read the next string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void InfoInput()
{
    string classID;
    string teacherName;
    int totalStudent;
    string topicClass;
    cout<<"Enter class ID"<<endl;
    getline(cin, classID);
    cout<<"Enter teacher's name"<<endl;
    getline(cin, teacherName);
    cout<<"Enter total number of students"<<endl;
    cin>>totalStudent;
    cout<<"Enter topic of class"<<endl;
    getline(cin,topicClass);
    getline(cin, topicClass);
    //cin>>topicClass;
}

int main ()
{

   InfoInput();

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `classID` and `teacherName` are local variables and disappear after execution leaves the function.  You'll have to figure out some way, like passing parameters by reference, to share the variables between functions.