# Code skips the getline statement. I tried both getline and cin with no success

Tags: c++

I read some answers regarding how to fix it but I'm trying to also understand the concept behind it (i.e. why does the first getline work fine).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
string ticker = "";
string date = "";
int pprice;
int sprice;

cout << "Enter the stock ticker =>" << endl;
getline(cin, ticker);
cout << "Enter the purchase price =>" << endl;
cin >> pprice;
```

IT WORKS FINE UNTIL IT GETS TO HERE:

```
cout << "Enter the sell date =>" << endl; 
getline(cin, date);      
cout << "Enter the sell price =>" << endl;
cin >> sprice;

cout << ticker << endl;

return 0;
}

/*OUTPUT:
Enter the stock ticker =>
XYZ
Enter the purchase price =>
12.34
Enter the sell date =>
Enter the sell price =>
12.34
XYZ
*/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cin and getline skipping input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input)

Comment: I actually tried that before posting this because cin.ignore(); did not work. It only causes the program to terminate.

Comment: You entered a float (12.34) while pprice (and sprice) should be an int. So pprice will be 12 and date .34.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not using `cin.ignore()` in the correct place. It should be used after `std::cin` and before `getline()`.

For Example:

```
int x;
string y;
cin >> x;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
getline(cin, y);
```

The idea is to remove the carriage returns, newlines etc that cin leaves behind on the stream which cause getline() to immediate take and return.