# spoj STRHH, unable to find bug. why extra "endl" in begining

Tags: c++, error-handling

[spoj question .unable to find error in solution. pls help](http://www.spoj.com/problems/STRHH)

Given a sequence of 2*k characters, please print every second character from the first half of the sequence. Start printing with the first character.

**Input**
In the first line of input your are given the positive integer t (1<=t<=100) - the number of test cases. In the each of the next t lines, you are given a sequence of 2*k (1<=k<=100) characters.

**Output**
For each of the test cases please please print every second character from the first half of a given sequence (the first character should appear).

> **Input:**
>   4 
>   your 
>   progress 
>   is 
>   noticeable
>
> **Output:**
>   y
>   po
>   i
>   ntc

[my solution getting "extra space" hence wrong result](http://ideone.com/o4DpIe)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void halfHalf(string ch){   
    int size=ch.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size/2;i+=2){
        cout<<ch[i];
        }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main() {
    string name[50];
    int numLine,i(0);
    cin>>numLine;

    while(i<=numLine){
        getline(cin,name[i]);
        halfHalf(name[i]);
        i++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: input and output are in NEW LINE

Comment: So you can get up to a hundred strings, and your array only have space for *50* strings? That won't work very well.

Comment: What's wrong with your output? What extra space are you talking about?

Comment: while debugging found this. 
after cin numline. getline(cin,name(i)) executes with BLANK input and goes to function where it enters ENDL

Comment: So why `i<=numLine` instead of `i<numLine`?

Comment: i did "<" insted of "<=" but then it leave the last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`cin.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after reading the first integer. This works for me

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    cin.ignore();
    while (T--) {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        for (int i = 0; i * 2 < s.size(); i += 2)
            cout << s[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/5vK5Sf)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553849/2425366) should be useful. It quotes

> If you're using getline after cin >> something, you need to flush the newline out of the buffer in between.

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you @Shreevardhan