# Why is my console application not waiting for lines 37 and 38?

Tags: c++

Please need help with this problem. When I run the executable file, the console is not giving me time to enter the characters as requested in line 37 and I'm not able to identify the issue. It only works when I comment out both for-loops. The code is shown below:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "../../Eigen/Eigen"
#include "../../Eigen/Dense"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("PipeThk_v1.0"));
    system("CLS");
    system("color F1");
    time_t rawtime_start;
    struct tm * timeinfo_start;
    time(&rawtime_start);
    timeinfo_start = localtime(&rawtime_start);
    printf(asctime(timeinfo_start));

    cout << "\nEnter nominal pipe sizes in 'in':\n";
    vector<double> npss;
    for (double nps; cin >> nps;)
    npss.push_back(nps);

    cout << "\n NPS\n";
    for (const auto& i : npss)
    cout << "\n " << i;

    time_t rawtime_end;
    struct tm * timeinfo_end;
    time(&rawtime_end);
    timeinfo_end = localtime(&rawtime_end);
    cout << endl << endl << asctime(timeinfo_end);

    cout << "\nEnter any character and hit enter to exit:\n";
    char ans;
    cin >> ans;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not your issue, but you don't need to have `cin` wait on a `char`, you can simply use `std::cin.get();`

Comment: Use `System("pause");` instead of your 35, 36 and 37 if you are on Windows but see [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) why it is not recommended

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `operator>>` to parse `std::cin` into a `double` variable.

`operator>>` stops reading input when it encounters a character that cannot be converted. That character, such as when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>, will remain in the stream's buffer and be immediately available to be read by `operator>>` on line 37 without any need to prompt the user for more input.

So, for example, if you entered `47` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the last `double` value, the value `47` gets parsed into your `double` variable, and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key gets read as a `\n` character by `std::cin >> ans`.

The lesson for today is: do not use `operator>>` to process interactive input from `std::cin` from the terminal. Use `std::getline()` to read one line of text at a time, an then construct a `std::istringstream` object to parse the line as needed.  Replace every occurence of `std::cin >> ...` with `std::getline(std::cin)` in order to avoid unexpected surprises with parsing interactive input.

That, of course, is not the only way to do it, but the one that requires the least amount of work, and results in the least amount of unexpected behavior.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `operator>>` to read input from `std::cin` directly.  You just have to clear its buffer to flush out any pending data before reading the last `char` so it will wait on the user, eg: `cin.clear(); cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); cin >> ans /*or cin.get()*/;`

Comment: I followed the flushing out buffer solution because I don't see any other cleaner way for collecting the data for my `npss` vector without the `operator>>`. Also I had to use `cin.ignore(10000, '\n')` instead because I was getting some error message about expected and identifier under the max() part. @Remy Lebeau can you comment on it?

Comment: @PipeTran Sam gave you a cleaner solution - use `std::getline()` to read lines and `std::istringstream` to parse each line. You can use `operator>>` on `std::istringstream`. As for the `numeric_limits` error, use `#include <limits>`.