# C++: Flawed console output on using a conditional statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a newbie to C++ (and to programming in general). I wrote a program that reads and writes staff contact details. This code works well:

```
// appropriate headers...

int main() 
{
    char trigger{};
    int options = 0;
    bool testing{};


    fileIps Inptbox;            // for entering new data
    char ext_title[20]; char ext_intercomNum[4]; char ext_dept[20];

    printf("%s", "Enter Officer's Title:\n");
    gets_s(ext_title, 20);
    printf("%s", "Enter Officer's Intercom Number:\n");
    gets_s(ext_intercomNum, 4);
    printf("%s", "Enter Officer's Department:\n");
    gets_s(ext_dept, 20);

    Inptbox.rcv_values(ext_title, ext_intercomNum, ext_dept);
    Inptbox.create_string();
    testing = Inptbox.validate();
    if (testing == true)
        return -1;
    else if (testing == false)
        Inptbox.write_string();

    // more code below...
```

My question is regarding the console output. I had tried to introduce conditional statements to enable selecting a *read* or *write* mode. The above code is for **writing** to file. There are more lines of code below for **reading** from file and they, too, worked okay.

My challenge is that once I introduce a conditional statement for the above code...

```
    printf("%s", "Enter 1 to WRITE DATA or 2 to READ DATA\n");
    cin >> options;
    if (options == 1)
    {
        fileIps Inptbox;           // for entering new data
        //... rest of code...
    }

    // more code below...
```

...the output on the console is flawed, as the prompt for the first entry is displayed but is totally skipped, forcing the user to enter '*Officer's Intercom Number*' first. The third prompt worked well.

To elaborate further, when I used `cin` to assign the value 1 to `options` (i.e. applying the condition), the console would immediately print...

```
Enter Officer's Title:

Enter Officer's Intercom Number:
```

...making it impossible for me to fill in the first entry (i.e. '*Title*').

I struggled with this and tried several things to fix it. I used `fgets()` and even tried it with `gets()`. I revisited my classes, yet nothing worked. I read widely on things like buffering, studied questions on this site and looked through various resources on `cstdio` as well as `ios_base` and its derived classes (which was good because I learned a bunch of other things). However, unless I removed that 'if' statement from my code, nothing I else I tried worked.

So, my question is: "How can this kind of behaviour be explained and how best could I implement my code to enable me toggle between read and write mode?"

I am working with **MS Visual Studio 2015**.

Comment: Just want to point out that `fileIps Inptbox` is confusing (to me at least). Generally classes have capitalised names, and variables non-capitalised - e.g. `FileIps inptbox`.

Comment: I'm very sorry. The class I use here is user-defined and I didn't want to define it here for the sake of brevity. And thanks for teaching me the convention...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but think your problem is to do with mixing `std::cin` and `gets_s`. Take a look at this [question for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input).

Comment: Okay. It's plausible, though I did try multiple I/O approaches. I will focus on your suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, @James. Not only was the problem solved, but more importantly, I understand why!

Answer (score 0):

Using the formatted extraction operator '>>' has its problems. In this case, it reads all values that can convert to an integer. However, you must give an enter to signal that you're ready. The >> operator does not process that newline. When the next time input is read, it sees the previously given newline character. Hence the 'Enter Officer's title' input is immediately set to a newline and continues. Try using something like:

```
std::string line;
getline(cin, line);
```

And test the string or convert it.