# Why my string isn't taking the input correctly the second time?

Tags: c++, string

My code takes a string and displays the even index position letters then after a space it shows the odd indexed letters.
Like if i give an input `Hacker` it should give `Hce akr`.
Now here my code isn't giving me the right answer for the second input.
Like on giving the 2nd input as `Rank` it should give `Rn ak`.
Instead of that it gives an `k` .Here it misses `R`.

---

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void f(string a) {

    string odd,even;
    for(int i=0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            even = even + a[i];
        } else {
            odd = odd + a[i];
        }
    }

    cout << even << " " << odd << "\n";//<<<<<<I THINK THIS \n IS THE 

      //PROBLEM BUT I NEED THIS \n.I OBESERVED THAT ON REMOVING \n, CODES
      // WORKS CORRECTLY.
}

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    string str;
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    for(int i=0; i < t; i++) {
        std::cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, str);
        f(str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `i != a.size()` instead as the condition,  `a[i] != '\0'` is a bit dodgy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cin and getline skipping input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input), check which ignore parameters to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the `std::cin.ignore()` outside of the loop.
The getline consumes the newline character, just the first input leaves it (`cin>>t`).

When you read e.g. an int or a char, the newline character after the input stays in the input stream. Thus now doing a getline would just read the newline character and you call `cin.ignore()` to consume the newline character. But then each `getline()` consumes the whole line including the newline character, so you don't have to call `cin.ignore()` and if you do, it will per default consume one character, here the 'R'.

Comment: thanks for your solution , but i don't understand why it was giving me wrong earlier.

Comment: Because after the first word from the input, the ignore() (in the loop) caused the next character, the 'R' from Rank, to be ignored.