# Program closes after entering two numbers

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << "Please enter two numbers" << std::endl;

    int v1, v2 = 0;

    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 << " and " << v2
        << " is " << v1 + v2 << std::endl;

    std::cin.get(); 

    return 0;
}
```

I added the cin.get() so that I could see the result in the terminal before it closes, but for some reason the program still closes immediately after printing the result. Is there a better way to prevent the window from closing immediately after running the code?

Comment: Run the program in a command prompt?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified - I'm compiling and running the code in Visual Studio 2017, so it opens what looks like a terminal, executes the code, and then closes.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input -- add `std::cin.ignore()` before `std::cin.get()`

Comment: `int v1, v2 = 0;` will assign 0 to `v2` and leave `v1` uninitialized

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
```

At this point you type in, for example:

```
4 5 <Enter>
```

(with the `<Enter>` key generating a newline character).

The first `>>` parses "4".

The second `>>` parses "5".

And your call to `get()` reads the newline character, `'\n'`.

And then your program immediately terminates.

## Moral of the story

Use `std::getline()` to read a line of text entered interactively, from a terminal, rather than the `>>` operator. That's what `std::getline()` is for.