# Getline() for the second line and split by space - C++

Tags: c++, getline

I'm trying to solve a problem that requires multiple inputs from the users. I'm used to Python, so the C++ syntax is a bit more complex to me.

What I mean:

**Input:**

```
1

30 40 50
```

**Output:**

```
30 40 50
```

I didn't find a single solution to this and I've been trying to find it all day.

What I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input1; cin >> input1;
    string input2;
    cin >> input2;
    getline(cin, input2);
    cout << input2;
}
```

And I don't seem to understand the getline() method properly.
What I get:

**Output:**

```
 40 50
```

**Expected Output:**

```
30 40 50
```

Comment: What do you think happens when you do `cin >> input2;` ?  Also it is kinda tricky to mix formatted input with getline.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I think of it as `input()` in Python

Comment: What is the first line with "1" supposed to signify?

Comment: `>>` reads input until a whitespace character or line break and puts it in the variable provided. If you're coming from Python, you should get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539) since it's hard to learn proper C++ from things like online tutorials

Comment: @FeiXiang Yeah.. It's very stressful just by trying to learn online. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cin and getline skipping input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input)

Comment: @FeiXiang: more importantly, `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace by default (unless you use `std::noskipws`), which includes line breaks, THEN it reads data until the next whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cin >> input2;

This reads 30.

> getline(cin, input2);

and this reads the rest of the line. Simply change the line:

```
cin >> input2;
```

for:

```
cin.ignore();
```

that way you don't read the first number in the second line and ignore the enter key.