# C++ programme behaving strangely

Tags: c++, output

I am learning C++.

I wrote a simple C++ programme to take in my name, my age, my wife's name, and my wife's age and print it on screen. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void myFunction();


int main() {
  myFunction();

  return 0;
}

void myFunction() {

  string hName;
  string wName;
  int hAge;
  int wAge;  

  cout << "Please enter your name:" << endl;

  getline(cin, hName);

  cout << "Enter your age:" << endl;

  cin >> hAge;

  cout << hName << " is " << hAge << " years old." << endl;

  cout << "\nPlease enter your wife's name:" << endl;

  getline(cin, wName);

  cout << "\nPlease enter your wife's age:" << endl;

  cin >> wAge;

  cout << wName << " is " << wAge << " years old." << endl;
}
```

I made the file:

```
make filename.cpp
```

And I ran the binary:

```
./filename
```

And this is the weird output:

```
Please enter your name:
Basil Ajith
Enter your age:
30
Basil Ajith is 30 years old.

Please enter your wife's name:

Please enter your wife's age:
Alfia Abubaker
 is 0 years old.
```

Right after I enter my name and age and the sentence is printed out, both sentences that prompt me to enter my wife's name and age are printed together. I enter my wife's age and the last line

```
 is 0 years old.
```

is printed and the programme exits.

Why this strange behaviour?

Comment: Possibly relevant (duplicate) questions: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/580083), [cin and getline skipping input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10553597/580083).

Comment: Using both `>>` and `getline`, like that, will not work the way you think it will work. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: Most common C++ question on stack overflow, by some distance.

Comment: Sorry, I only did a cursory search for duplicate questions.