# Check all occurrences of a letter appear before another letter C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, letter, find-occurrences

I have a string S consisting of N letters 'a' or 'b'. This should return true when all occurrences of 'a' are before all occurrences of 'b' and return false otherwise.

b does not need to occur in S and a does not need to occur in S

For example

```
S='aabbb' returns true 
S = 'ba' returns false
S = 'aaa' returns true
S= 'b' returns true
S='abba' returns false
```

this is my solution but it displays 1 extra true. I don't know why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> vec;
    int n;
    string item;
    int contora=0,contorb=0;
    cout<<"n: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    for(int i=0;i<= n;i++){
       getline(cin, item);
       //cin>>item;
     vec.push_back(item);
     }
        
    for (int j=0; j <= n; j++) {
            cout << vec[j];
    }
   cout<<endl;

    for (auto of:vec) {
        if (of.find("ba") != std::string::npos)
            cout << "false";
            else 
            cout<<"true";
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is "one extra true" ? Please include example input, actual and expected output in the question

Comment: the loop `for(int i=0;i<= n;i++)` reads `n+1` strings, that might cause one unexpected output

Comment: you would see that extra input in the the loop where you print the contents of `vec` though, because that loop has `n+1` iterations as well

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I don't understand.  Why is `S='b'` returning true?  There are no `a`s in that string so there are no preceding `a`s.  So, by definition it should return "false otherwise".

Comment: IMHO, this assignment is best modelled after a state machine.  Draw out the state machine, then implement.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some debug output to the code shows a couple of issues:

1. The first `for` loop reads in `n+1` strings, while we are expecting the user to enter only `n` strings. The second `for` loop also prints `n+1` strings, although that's not a problem, because the vector contains `n+1` elements.
2. Due to mixing both `std::cin >>` and `std::getline` for reading user input, the first string read with `std::getline` is empty. You would need whether to:

   - use `std::getline` for all the user input readings (and, for `n`, convert the string to a number), or
   - flush the input buffer with `cin.ignore` after the `std::cin >>`, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553849/260313).

The code below fixes those two issues and adds some debug output (it also follows a few best practices such as, not `using namespace std;`, defining variables next to their first use, value-initializing local variables, and using block braces even for one-line blocks).

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/E88xrK89G)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cin, cout
#include <limits>
#include <string>  // getline
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n{};
    std::cout << "n: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << n << "\n\n";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::vector<std::string> vec{};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
        std::string item{};
        std::getline(std::cin, item);
        std::cout << "item: " << i << ": '" << item << "'\n";
        vec.push_back(item);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (auto& of : vec) {
        std::cout << "'" << of << "': ";
        if (of.find("ba") != std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "false\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "true\n";
        }
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   n: 5
//
//   Enter a string: item: 0: 'aabbb'
//   Enter a string: item: 1: 'ba'
//   Enter a string: item: 2: 'aaa'
//   Enter a string: item: 3: 'b'
//   Enter a string: item: 4: 'abba'
//
//   'aabbb': true
//   'ba': false
//   'aaa': true
//   'b': true
//   'abba': false
```

---

For this particular case, you could also use `std::is_partitioned`. This algorithm tells you if all the elements of a range that satisfy a given predicate appear before all the elements that don't (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_partitioned)). The predicate would check if a character is equal to `'a'`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/GK18coren)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // is_partitioned
#include <cstring>  // strlen
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    for (auto&& s : { "aabbb", "ba", "aaa", "b", "abba" }) {
        fmt::print("'{}': {}\n", s, std::is_partitioned(s, s + strlen(s),
            [](unsigned char c) { return c == 'a'; }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wording it differently, you're trying to check if there are any characters in the string that come after `a`. If the answer is no, your function will return `true`, and `false` otherwise.

```
bool HasCorrectOrder(char prefix_char, char suffix_char, std::string_view str) {
  if (str.empty()) {
    return true;
  }
  // Run through all the preceeding characters.
  int index = 0;
  while (str[index] == prefix_char && index < str.size()) {
    ++index;
  }
  // At this point, if we've reached the end of the string, that means there are
  // no characters after the preceeding character. So we can return true.
  if (index == str.size()) {
    return true;
  }
  // As there are more characters left, they should all be equal to the
  // suffix_char in order for the ordering to be correct.
  while (str[index] == suffix_char && index < str.size()) {
    ++index;
  }
  return (index == str.size());
}
```

Running a quick check:

```
void RunTest() {
  std::vector<std::string> test_strings = {"aabbb", "ba", "aaa", "b", "abba"};
  for (std::string_view str : test_strings) {
    std::cout << "S = " << str << " returns "
              << (HasCorrectOrder(/*prefix_char=*/'a',
                                  /*suffix_char=*/'b', str) ? "true" : "false")
              << std::endl;
  }
}
```

returns:

```
S = aabbb returns true
S = ba returns false
S = aaa returns true
S = b returns true
S = abba returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the loop logic, here is another simple solution you could use, with the is_sorted algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    // ...

    for (auto of : vec)
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::ranges::is_sorted(of);
}
```

This compiles with C++20 support, and it works because strings are ranges of characters, for which an `operator<` is defined. It happens to be the case that 'a' < 'b', so this simple expression is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find "ba" occurrences.
C++ string type already provides such function. Complexity is linear on string length O(n)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void checker(const std::string S) 
{
    if (S.find("ba") != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "false" << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "true" << '\n';
    }
}
```